# Where is the sculpt tool in 2.70?

Tags: interface, sculpting

Im following the Blender 2.6 tutorial from lynda and I can't find the sculpt tool in sculpt mode in Blender 2.70.

In 2.6 the sculpt tool is under the texture now the only options I have are:

- Texture
- Stroke
- Curve
- Topology
- Symmetry Lock

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In blender 2.70 just as in 2.60 the Sculpt Tools can be found under *Brush* once in *Sculpt Mode*.

1. In the 3d header switch to sculpt mode, note your active selection needs to be a sculptable mesh

   [image]
2. In the *Tools* tab at the very top you will see the brush section. Exapnd it and you will have access to the sculpt brushes

   [image]